# Is it possible to disable certain weekdays in DatePickerDialog?

Tags: java, android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I need a DatePicker for a subscription service where the customer can select view dates. But not every day is available. For example on Wednesdays is no delivery.

Is it possible to disable specific week days?

Or do I have to make an alert afterwards to tell him this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this project you will find the logic you need. 
[DatePicker without sundays](https://www.open-sourced.de/show_article.php?articleid=56)

Relevant snippet:

```
 if (choosenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 
                    Calendar.SUNDAY || 
                    now.compareTo(choosenDate) < 0) {
                    dateTextView.setTextColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#ff0000")
                    );
                    ((Button) dialog.getButton(
                    AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE))
                        .setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    dateTextView.setTextColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#000000")
                    );
                    ((Button) dialog.getButton(
                    AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE))
                        .setEnabled(true);
                }
```

You can rewrite this, of course, to block Wednesdays or any other days 
of the week. The code was written in the OnChangeListener of the Datepicker 
in the last java lines of the sample project.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one example for  datepicker,  display only week days and allow to select next 10days with active state.
(Weekends disabled on selection)

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: "+10d",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
});
```